Does the Subjacency Condition hold cross-linguistically?
In my introductory syntax class, we learned of the Subjacency Condition as a unifying framework for all the rules of phrasal movement in English we had observed so far. The Subjacency Condition states that a phrase cannot move past more than one bounding node without landing on some "island" / empty node (but can move again past that island, if so needed). This unified a number of constraints we had observed (a full list can be found on page 281 of Sportiche et al's An Introduction to Syntactic Analysis and Theory).
Though our textbook makes less so an emphasis on it, preferring instead to get students comfortable with syntactic analysis as a whole in a language they are familiar with: it is obvious that all of our principles and conditions cannot hold across all languages. However: the Subjacency Condition is remarkably broad, especially given the idea of a "bounding node" is intentionally ill-defined, as different structures can become or not become bounding nodes in different contexts.
Excluding languages with free word order, because to my understanding they already challenge phrase structure as a whole - accounting for different formulations of "bounding nodes", does the Subjacency Condition or something similar to it hold for all languages? If so, is this an argument for a universal grammar? If not, what are some languages it does and does not hold for?
